# Why is the variable input2 = -1?

Tags: c

Why is the variable `input2` assigned -1 and why does it give me a memory value when I run the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int input1;
    int input2 =  -1;

    while(input2 != 0)  
    {
        scanf("%d", &input1);
        scanf("%d", &input2);
        printf("Sum: %d\n", input1 + input2);
    }

    if(input1==99)
        puts("Finish.");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You need to clarify.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and tell us (a) what you expect to see, and (b) what you're actually seeing?

Comment: This is just a slightly hackish way to ensure that `input2` isn't set to `0` when the `while` starts for the first time.  `input2` could be set to any value except `0` and the code would work,

Comment: @Jonas Rye Nielsen You may want to check this out: [How do I ask a good question? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I suggest you to read through it as this will help you gain more reputation and get a better and quicker answer

Comment: @FedericoBaù Thank you I will read up on that.

Answer (score 4):

You have a `while` loop that continues as long as `input2` is not equal to `0`, so in order to enter it the variable needs to be initialized with some arbitrary value that isn't `0`. Functionally, you could have used `1`, `-123`, `999` or any other non zero value and get the same effect.

Comment: Thank you that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary value with no reason. If uninitialized, it will cause undetermined
behavior whether the while loop is taken or not (depending on what garbage is inside `input2`). The writer of this code wanted the while loop to enter. Could have rewritten it

```
int input1;
int input2;

do  
{
    scanf("%d", &input1);
    scanf("%d", &input2);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", input1 + input2);
} while(input2 != 0);
```

Comment: Re “If uninitialized, it will cause undefined behavior”: No, if uninitialized, `input2` will have an indeterminate value. There is a provision in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 that causes use of uninitialized automatic objects to have undefined behavior, but it does not apply because it requires the object’s address not be taken, and this program takes address of `input2` in `scanf("%d", &input2);`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonas Rye Nielsen this program is just a simple calculator to add 2 Integer number and that's it.

Now in order to quit and program, what it does is to check the **second Input** with some logic behind it.

If you enter a 0 to add 2 integer (or anyway in any kind of addition really) add a 0 would just make no sense at all, hence the progam is implicitly assuming that you want to exit it!.